# Java how to find the middle of a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors

I'm writing a function that tries to find the middle of a 2d array, and here's what I have so far:

```
int findMiddle(int[][] grid,int [] m) {
    int[] list = new int[grid.length*grid[0].length];
    int listPos = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < grid.length; j++) {
            list[listPos++] = grid[i][j];
        }
    }
    int middle = m.length/2;
    if (m.length%2 == 1) {
        return m[middle];
    } else {
        return (m[middle-1] + m[middle]) / 2.0;
    }
}
```

Suppose I have an array of

```
{{0, 1, 2, 3},
 {4, 5, 6, 7},
 {8, 9, 0, 1}}
```

It should return 6, as it is integer division.
Also, the definition of middle in this code is the middle integer of the whole original array (needless to say if it is sorted or not).

How would I do this? ( my code also doesn't compile)

Comment: Is the array sorted row wise ? If not, You can sort the array row wise then take the middle element of the middle column.

Comment: Bubble sort and then take the middle value of the middle array. hah.

Comment: I think you are confusing people with your misuse of the word 'median'. You really mean that you want the middle value of the array, not the median in a statistical sense. I suggest you change 'median' to 'middle' in your question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This compiles, and will give you the middle number in your sequence, or the average of the middle two if it splits the middle:

```
  static double findMiddle(int[][] grid) {
    int[] list = new int[grid.length*grid[0].length];
    int listPos = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            list[listPos++] = grid[i][j];
        }
    }
    int middle = list.length/2;
    if ((list.length%2) == 1) {
        return list[middle];
    }
    return (list[middle-1] + list[middle]) / 2.0;
  }
```

However, I suspect you'll want to sort you numbers after you combine them into a single array, before you find the middle numbers. (as piyush121 commented)

Comment: i forgot to say that it's not needed to sort the array before finding the median

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your definition of 'median' is correct (the middle number of an odd length set or the average of the two middle numbers of an even length set), and if grid[][] is sorted, and if grid[][] is a square array (i.e. grid.length = grid[i].length for all i in 0..length-1, then you don't need to copy data to another array. The following should suffice:

```
 static int findMiddle(int[][] grid) {
    int l = grid.length;
    if (l%2 == 1) {
       return grid[l/2][l/2];
    } else {
    return (grid[l/2-1][l-1]+grid[l/2][0])/2;
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your existing code it seems you are defining 'median' as the middle value in the matrix if all values were put into a single row-wise list. In other words you don't need to cope with odd numbers of rows (when two numbers from the same column are in the middle) or odd numbers of rows and columns (when there are four numbers in the middle).

If that definition is correct then you can cope with all the complexity of uneven rows by streaming all values and then selecting the middle ones.

For your interest, here's a Java 8 solution that does that:

```
int[] flat = Arrays.stream(grid).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).toArray();
double middle = Arrays.stream(flat).skip(flat.length / 2).limit(1 + flat.length % 2)
    .average().getAsDouble();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[ To get the value of the center of Matrix ( 2-dimensional ) Array of an odd squared matrix Array ]
you have to follow these steps ;

 1. Divide your array by 2 and check the remainder is equal to 1 
 2. Store it in a middle variable
 3. Get value of Matrix[middle][middle] e.g ( 3 , 3 ) or ( 5 , 5 ) etc.
 4. Return the value
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
public static int getMiddleValue(int[][] matrix) {
        // Check if the array is not empty
        if (matrix == null || matrix.length == 0 || matrix.length != matrix[0].length) {
            return -1; // Invalid array
        }

        // Check if the number of rows and columns are odd
        int numRows = matrix.length;
        int numCols = matrix[0].length;
        if (numRows % 2 == 0 || numCols % 2 == 0) {
            return -1; // Not a square matrix with odd dimensions
        }

        // Find the middle index
        int middleIndex = numRows / 2;

        // Retrieve the middle value`enter code here`
        int middleValue = matrix[middleIndex][middleIndex];

        return middleValue;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).